# Notificar duplicado de datos en PHP

Tags: php

Saludos a todos les escribe para que me oriente en un problema que tengo con PHP.

Tengo un sistema de registro con PHP y MySQL, nada del otro mundo y todo funciona muy bien, pero tengo el inconveniente no puedo hacer que me indique que existe datos duplicados en este caso la “Cedula Inmobiliaria” (cedula_inmueble) para que luego me arroje una alerta indicando que dicho dato ya se encuentra registrado.

No hago que funcione y siempre me indica en una página en blanco el mensaje “error Duplicate entry 'GTTR' for key 'PRIMARY'”

Espero me puedan asesorar.

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once "../../config/database.php";

if (empty($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['password'])){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php?alert=1'>";
}

else {
    if ($_GET['act']=='insert') {
        if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) {
     
            $cedula_inmueble  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cedula_inmueble']));
            $numero_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['numero_casa']));
            $manzana_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['manzana_casa']));
            $calle_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['calle_casa']));
            $tipo_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['tipo_casa']));
            $estado_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['estado_casa']));

            $creado_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

  
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comunidad_casa(cedula_inmueble,numero_casa,manzana_casa,calle_casa,tipo_casa,estado_casa,creado_user,modificado_user) 
                                            VALUES('$cedula_inmueble','$numero_casa','$manzana_casa','$calle_casa','$tipo_casa','$estado_casa','$creado_user', '$creado_user')")
                                            or die('error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));  
 
            if ($query) {
         
                header("location: ../../main.php?module=vivienda&alert=1");
            }   
        }   
    } 
       ?>
```

Comment: entiendo que ese mensaje te viene por el die() que tienes despues de la consulta, no? podrias quitarlo y poner un "else" en el if siguiente, de esa manera sabrias que ha habido algun error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de dejar que el motor de base de datos sea quien revise si hay duplicados, es mejor ejecutar una consulta para saber si la cédula ya está registrada.

Sugiero usar `SELECT COUNT(*)` porque siempre devuelve una fila con la cantidad de registros que coinciden o cero, si no hay coincidencia.

```
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta FROM comunidad_casa
            WHERE cedula_inmueble = '$cedula_inmueble'")
            or die('error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        if($res['cuenta'] > 0) {
           die('La cédula ya está dada de alta.');
        }

        // Ahora sí puedes insertar
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comunidad_casa (cedula_inmueble, numero_casa,
            manzana_casa, calle_casa, tipo_casa, estado_casa, creado_user, modificado_user) 
            VALUES ('$cedula_inmueble', '$numero_casa', '$manzana_casa', '$calle_casa',
            '$tipo_casa', '$estado_casa', '$creado_user', '$creado_user')")
            or die('error '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la asesoría seguir con tu consejo ahora funciona muy bien

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que meter un bloque try catch. Para ello, en la parte del Try, debes poner la parte de código que se va a ejecutar de manera normal, esto es, lo que tienes ahora y en el bloque cacth, debes capturar la excepción que se te genera.

La documentación Oficial la puedes conultar en [La clase mysqli_sql_exception](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php). Y mas o menos, te quedará tu código de esta manera.

```
    <?php
    session_start();


require_once "../../config/database.php";
try{
   if (empty($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['password'])){
       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php?alert=1'>";
   }
   else {
    if ($_GET['act']=='insert') {
        if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) {
     
            $cedula_inmueble  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cedula_inmueble']));
            $numero_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['numero_casa']));
            $manzana_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['manzana_casa']));
            $calle_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['calle_casa']));
            $tipo_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['tipo_casa']));
            $estado_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['estado_casa']));

            $creado_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

  
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comunidad_casa(cedula_inmueble,numero_casa,manzana_casa,calle_casa,tipo_casa,estado_casa,creado_user,modificado_user) 
                                            VALUES('$cedula_inmueble','$numero_casa','$manzana_casa','$calle_casa','$tipo_casa','$estado_casa','$creado_user', '$creado_user')");  
 
            if ($query) {
         
                header("location: ../../main.php?module=vivienda&alert=1");
            }   
        }   
    } 
   }
   catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            throw $e;
   }
       ?>
```

Comment: segun veo en https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php mysqli_query no lanza ninguna excepcion, por lo que ponerlo dentro de try/catch no te permitiria gestionar ese error. De hecho, mantienes el die() en el codigo, con lo que nunca se lanzará el catch

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que mysqli_query no detecta como error el no poder hacer un insert, lo único que puedes hacer es comprobar primero si la cedula_inmueble existe o hacer el insert y comprobar con mysqli_affected_rows si se ha insertado. Lo segundo sería así:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "../../config/database.php";

if (empty($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['password'])){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php?alert=1'>";
}

else {
    if ($_GET['act']=='insert') {
        if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) {
     
            $cedula_inmueble  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cedula_inmueble']));
            $numero_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['numero_casa']));
            $manzana_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['manzana_casa']));
            $calle_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['calle_casa']));
            $tipo_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['tipo_casa']));
            $estado_casa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['estado_casa']));

            $creado_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

  
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comunidad_casa(cedula_inmueble,numero_casa,manzana_casa,calle_casa,tipo_casa,estado_casa,creado_user,modificado_user) 
                                            VALUES('$cedula_inmueble','$numero_casa','$manzana_casa','$calle_casa','$tipo_casa','$estado_casa','$creado_user', '$creado_user')");  
 
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) == 0) {
                //Si entramos aquí es que no se ha insertado
         
                header("location: ../../main.php?module=vivienda&alert=1");
            }   
        }   
    } 
       ?>
```

El problema de esto, es que solo sabes que el insert falla, no si es por la duplicidad o por otro error.

Un saludo.